# Return data based on 2 variables

Tags: python, pandas

First post for me. Working on a learning assignment with a housing data set. There are negative values for sq footage and zero valuees for bedrooms and bathrooms. I want to narrow the data to those rows. I've done:

```
sac_new[sac_new['sq_ft'] == 0]
```

and

```
sac_new[sac_new['beds'] == 0]
```

I want to combine them to I get rows with 0 sq_ft but 1 or more beds. I'm thinking this should work:

```
sac_new[sac_new['sq_ft'] == 0], sac_new[sac_new['beds'] >0]
```

Hopefully the above will give you an idea of where I'm going wrong and how much of a novice I am!

(I should add, it does return something but it is not formatted in a table and it includes rows with 0 beds...)

Comment: How is `sac_new` defined?

Comment: Those aren't standard Python lists, right? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine this filters using the `&` operator with the same technique you have been using before. This would the code:

```
sac_filtered = sac_new[(sac_new['sq_ft'] == 0) & (sac_new['beds'] > 0)]
```

Comment: And there it is! Thank you so much.

Comment: What would you recommend @blhsing, if using logical operator `and` would return a `ValueError`? Feel free to accept my answer if it helps you John :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Never mind. I just realized this is about the `pandas` framework.

Comment: Cheers, I'm self-taught so there's a lot I'm missing even if it might be "basic" for experienced coders, that's why I'm always open for suggestions.

Comment: Can I chuck another question in here if it is about the same data set or do I need to start a fresh? Also, is there an etiquette on how many questions one can post? Don't want to take the proverbial...

Comment: There might be a daily limit, but I have never heard of someone reaching it while being serious (not a spammer). Furthermore, ask here and if I can't find an easy answer, I'll probably suggest you to open a new one.

Comment: @ CeliusStingher So this one I'm a bit blank on. The size of my dataset is 985rows,12columns. Amongst the columns are values for 'beds', 'rooms' and 'sq_ft'. 171 rows have 0 sq_ft values. 63 rows have 0 sq_ft but values for beds and baths and the other 108 have 0 sq_ft, 0 baths and 0 beds. I'm thinking the 108 rows could be empty plots of land but the 63 rows missing sq_ft values must be wrong....

Comment: Don't want to drop them as they have other useful values so I'm thinking I could write a block of code that looks through the data set for the number of occurrences of each combination of beds and baths (there are between 0-8 beds and 0-5 baths) and then for each combination it totals the sq_ft and calculates the mean. Then that mean could be applied to each respective combination of beds and baths for the 0 value sq_ft rows.

Comment: Conscious I may not be providing nearly enough info so apologies if this is mind bending!

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are saying, it's a bit more complicated, open a new question and post the link here as a comment so I can check it as soon as you post it please!

Comment: Will do and THANK YOU!

Comment: @ CeliusStingher - here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533526/how-to-handle-missing-values