# How to handle missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a housing dataset.

```
sac_new.head()    

street  city    zip state   beds    baths   sq__ft  type    sale_date   price   latitude    longitude
        0   3526 HIGH ST    SACRAMENTO  95838   CA  2   1   836 Residential Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008    59222   38.631913   -121.434879
        1   51 OMAHA CT SACRAMENTO  95823   CA  3   1   1167    Residential Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008    68212   38.478902   -121.431028
        2   2796 BRANCH ST  SACRAMENTO  95815   CA  2   1   796 Residential Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008    68880   38.618305   -121.443839
        3   2805 JANETTE WAY    SACRAMENTO  95815   CA  2   1   852 Residential Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008    69307   38.616835   -121.439146
        4   6001 MCMAHON DR SACRAMENTO  95824   CA  2   1   797 Residential Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008    81900   38.519470   -121.435768

sac_new.describe()

    zip beds    baths   sq__ft  price   latitude    longitude
count   985.000000  985.000000  985.000000  985.000000  985.000000  985.000000  985.000000
mean    95750.697462    2.911675    1.776650    1312.918782 233715.951269   38.445121   -121.193371
std 85.176072   1.307932    0.895371    856.123224  139088.818896   5.103637    5.100670
min 95603.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -984.000000 -210944.000000  -121.503471 -121.551704
25% 95660.000000    2.000000    1.000000    950.000000  145000.000000   38.482704   -121.446119
50% 95762.000000    3.000000    2.000000    1304.000000 213750.000000   38.625932   -121.375799
75% 95828.000000    4.000000    2.000000    1718.000000 300000.000000   38.695589   -121.294893
max 95864.000000    8.000000    5.000000    5822.000000 884790.000000   39.020808   38.668433
```

There are zero values I need to deal with

```
sac_new.beds.value_counts()
3    413
4    258
2    133
0    108
5     59
1      9
6      3
8      1
Name: beds, dtype: int64

sac_new.baths.value_counts()
2    544
1    179
3    132
0    108
4     19
5      2
Name: baths, dtype: int64

sac_new.sq_ft.value_counts()
0       171
1120      8
795       6
1410      5
1039      5
       ... 
988       1
1656      1
876       1
1659      1
1235      1
Name: sq_ft, Length: 603, dtype: int64
```

I'm thinking the rows with zero beds, baths and sq_ft could be plots of land so might want to keep. But the rows with zero sq_ft but values for beds and baths must be an error. I don't think I should drop the rows. I think I should add values for the sq_ft and base them on the mean sq_ft of other rows. So the first question is whether this is a smart idea or not?

If it is then I'm thinking it could be achieved with a block of code that looks for the mean sq_ft of each combination of beds and baths. So, how many rows have 1 bed and 1 bath and whats the mean of the total sq_ft. How many have 1 bed and 2 baths... 2 beds and 1 bath, 2 beds and 2 baths etc. Then the mean for each could be added to the zero sq_ft value for the corresponding properties.

Or it would be quicker to start by checking the combination of baths and beds for the 63 zero sq_ft rows that have bath and bed values and then just calculating the mean sq_ft of those combinations as there may well be less than there are in the rest of the dataset.

But that's as far as my tiny brain can get me at this stage. Can anyone help? This is my first day posting on stackoverflow so if I'm formatting wrong or going about explaining things wrong do let me know.

Comment: What do you eventually plan to do with the data ? It seems your dataset is already small, so if you plan on using this for a model, I'm not sure how accurate the model could be.

Comment: I would also suggest to check for outliers when you calculate the mean. If there are some outliers, the mean may not be a correct representation of the sq_ft. You would instead have to consider using the median.

Comment: @Gary This is a learning assignment. We're ultimately trying to predict price. So as I think about it, I don't think dropping 172 rows from 985 will have a negative impact but either way, it'll be good to show my thinking and I'm keen to see how this could be achieved.

Comment: You will be losing nearly 20% of your data! When building a predictive model, having more data is always useful. As I mentioned earlier, I would first check for outliers and see if these outliers change the mean sq_ft value drastically. If they don't, you can use the mean. Otherwise, use the median.

Comment: I hear you. I will play about with that. Thanks. Should I still expect someone to help with the code? Still learning how this works.